# Which authenticate used AKS to create Azure resource?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I would like to know under whose authority AKS is creating the resource.

I'm trying to create an Internal Loadbalancer in AKS, but it fails without permissions.
However, I don't know who to give that privilege to.
The account that connected to AKS or the managed identity of AKS ? Or something else ?
Is the account that connected to AKS in the first place the same as the account that creates the AKS resources ?
It would be great if you could tell me the source of the information as well, as I need the documentation to explain it to my boss.
Best regards.

Comment: Nice to meet you, thank you for your answer.
Perfectly the information I wanted!

Comment: Glad to be of Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to create an Internal Loadbalancer in AKS, but it fails
> without permissions. However, I don't know who to give that privilege
> to. The account that connected to AKS or the managed identity of AKS ?
> Or something else ?

You will have to ***provide the required permissions to the managed identity*** of the AKS Cluster . So for your requirement to ***[`create a ILB in AKS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb)*** you need to give `Network Contributor` Role to the identity.

You can refer this ***[`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal?tabs=azure-cli#delegate-access-to-other-azure-resources)*** on ***How to delegate access for AKS to access other Azure resources***.

> Is the account that connected to AKS in the first place the same as
> the account that creates the AKS resources ?

The account which is connected to AKS is same as the account that created the AKS resources from Azure Portal (***User Account***) But different while accessing the Azure resources from inside the AKS (***Managed Identity / Service Principal***).

For more information you can refer this ***[`Microsoft Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity)***.